# problem build fhir with german basis profil

Tags: hl7-fhir

i use vb.net with visualStudio. i have installed the nuget Hl7.Fhir Version3.6.0 and other Hl7.Fhir-nugets (serializer a.s.o V3.6.0)

i have a Problem to build a fhir  with resource organization(for example, same with patient) with
german basis profil (https://simplifier.net/ditconnectathon/kbvprforpatient).
I init extension with URL and value, i have the organization and the address and the line. i can add enumerables to line, but no extension.
i am a newbie... All other resources i can build und serialize. My Question: is this a porblem with me and you can show me a solution, or is this (worst case) a problem with  Fhir rh4 and the german basis profil. What is then the solution....?

here some primitive code :

```
dim organization as new organzation
dim adr as new address
dim ext as new extension 'i have a function to make extension returns
ext=FunctionBuildExtension(url,value)
adr.line=new string() {city,street}
'    here should placed the addExtension, but i dont know how...
'    adr.line.???
organzation.address.add(adr)
```

this i want to have:
[fhir.organization.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ejze.jpg)

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The Address.Line is of the native .Net string type, which indeed does not know anything about extensions. You should also have an Address.LineElement which can take an extension.

Here's an example in C# of adding an extension to a primitive typed element: https://docs.fire.ly/projects/Firely-NET-SDK/model/extensions.html